# SQL injection: Is this line safe?

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I have this line:

```
$sql = "UPDATE votes SET up=up+1 WHERE id='{$p}'";
```

Now from what I've read one way of sql injection is caused by not "closing" sql queries properly which allows hackers to add additional info.

So my question is, is that line safe as to me the `up=up+1` has not been "closed" but if I set it like this `up='up+1'` which to me makes it "closed" it does not work.

row up type is `int(11)` if that makes any difference.

**Update:**

`$p` is sanitized with a function

```
function sanitize($foo) { 
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true) { 
 $foo = stripslashes($foo); 
} 
return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($foo)); 
}
```

Comment: That statement looks pretty safe to me except you just need to make sure $p is always number before this statement.

Comment: Never sanitize. Escape. sanitizing depends on you knowing every possible route of attack and filtering specifically for it. Anytime a new attack route is discovered, your function is useless. Whereas escaping handles ALL attacks.

Comment: If you are concerned about SQL injection attacks, then you should limit database access through stored procedures and views.  That said, the particular query looks pretty safe, especially since $p is checked by a function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff parameterized queries can offer the same "security" that stored procedures can.

Comment: @Marc B: Sorry I think I may have used the wrong word "sanitized" thats just what I call my function (see op edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `up=up+1` is not vulnerable because it does not accept user input via a variable.  It is merely incrementing an `INT` value already in your database.

The `WHERE id='{$p}'` *may* be vulnerable, however, if the variable `$p` is not properly filtered and escaped, but as you added above, it has been sanitized by a function.  Hopefully the sanitize function goes as far as checking the appropriate type of the variable (be it an int or string or whatever) and checks the appropriate bounds for it.

As always, the safest method is to make use of prepared statements and parameterized queries rather than pass any variables directly into a SQL string.  Most of the database APIs available in PHP for the various RDBMS' support prepared statements. (Notably *not* the `mysql_*()` functions, however).

Comment: Thanks, like I said in op $p has been sanitized using a function  `function sanitize($foo) {
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true)
  {
   $foo = stripslashes($foo);
}
   return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($foo));
}`

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe, unless `$p` is properly escaped.  Otherwise imagine...

> $p = "foo'; DROP TABLE votes; SELECT '1"

Then you'd end up executing something like:

```
UPDATE votes SET up=up+1 WHERE id='foo'; DROP TABLE votes; SELECT '1';
```

That wouldn't be very pretty...